# Why Spring Boot/JPA creates constraints names like this fkm5pcdf557o18ra19dajf7u26a?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, constraints

I have an entity called City:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "cities")
public class City implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Department department;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Integer code;
}
```

In this case if I not specify a name for the field Department it creates a field called department_id in my table "cities", that's Ok but when I see the Constraints created appears a constraint with name fkcl2xocc3mnys8b84bw2dog35e. Why this name? Does it make any sense?

[image]

This is my yaml jpa configuration:

```
spring:
    profiles: development
    datasource: 
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lalala
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
        sql-script-encoding: UTF-8
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    data.jpa.repositories.enabled: true
    jpa:
        generate-ddl: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
            show_sql: true
            use_sql_comments: true
            format_sql: true
            type: trace
            jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        properties:
            hibernate:
                jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: try `@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "YOUR_OWN_NAME"))` annotation

Comment: Thanks krokodilko but everything is fine with my database, no problem. I just want to know why that name? If it makes any sense.

Comment: Well, then you need to ask Hibernate team why they implemented this in that way. Somehow they had to do it, they did it like that, this was a design decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate generates a constraint name by concatenating table and properties names and convert the result to `MD5`. It is needed, because of the constraint names length restriction in some databases. For an example, in the Oracle database, a foreign key name length can't be more than 30 symbols length.

This code snippet from Hibernate source [org.hibernate.mapping.Constraint](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/mapping/Constraint.java)

```
/**
 * If a constraint is not explicitly named, this is called to generate
 * a unique hash using the table and column names.
 * Static so the name can be generated prior to creating the Constraint.
 * They're cached, keyed by name, in multiple locations.
 *
 * @return String The generated name
 */
public static String generateName(String prefix, Table table, Column... columns) {
    // Use a concatenation that guarantees uniqueness, even if identical names
    // exist between all table and column identifiers.

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "table`" + table.getName() + "`" );

    // Ensure a consistent ordering of columns, regardless of the order
    // they were bound.
    // Clone the list, as sometimes a set of order-dependent Column
    // bindings are given.
    Column[] alphabeticalColumns = columns.clone();
    Arrays.sort( alphabeticalColumns, ColumnComparator.INSTANCE );
    for ( Column column : alphabeticalColumns ) {
        String columnName = column == null ? "" : column.getName();
        sb.append( "column`" ).append( columnName ).append( "`" );
    }
    return prefix + hashedName( sb.toString() );
}

/**
 * Hash a constraint name using MD5. Convert the MD5 digest to base 35
 * (full alphanumeric), guaranteeing
 * that the length of the name will always be smaller than the 30
 * character identifier restriction enforced by a few dialects.
 * 
 * @param s
 *            The name to be hashed.
 * @return String The hased name.
 */
public static String hashedName(String s) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
        md.reset();
        md.update( s.getBytes() );
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger( 1, digest );
        // By converting to base 35 (full alphanumeric), we guarantee
        // that the length of the name will always be smaller than the 30
        // character identifier restriction enforced by a few dialects.
        return bigInt.toString( 35 );
    }
    catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e ) {
        throw new HibernateException( "Unable to generate a hashed Constraint name!", e );
    }
}
```

You can generate your own constraint names (unique and foreign key) using `ImplicitNamingStrategy`. You can refer [Hibernate5NamingStrategy](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/cfg/strategy/hibernate5/Hibernate5NamingStrategy.java) , as an example.

Answer (score 3):

This might be the default name generated by the provider. You can use `ForeignKey` annotation to specify the name

```java
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_NAME"))
```